# How can I specify a class attribute in new_tag()?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm currently using BeautifulSoup4 with Python 2.7 and trying to instantiate a new tag, with a certain `class` attribute. I know how to use attributes such as `style`:

```
div = soup.new_tag('div', style='padding-left: 10px', attr2='...', ...)
```

However, if I try to do this with the `class` reserved word, I get an error (invalid syntax).

```
div = soup.new_tag('div', class='left_padded', attr2='...', ...) # Throws error
```

I have also tried with `'class'='...'`, but this is also invalid. I *can* use `Class='...'`, but then the output is not properly compliant (all lowercase attribute names).

I am aware that I can do the following:

```
div = soup.new_tag('div', attr2='...', ...)
div['class'] = 'left_padded'
```

But this does not look elegant or intuitive. My research in the docs and on Google were fruitless, as "class" is a common keyword that is unrelated to the search results I want.

Is there a way I can specify `class` as an attribute in `new_tag()`?

Comment: For what it's worth, my opinion is that `div['class']` looks very intuitive -- setting the property of the dict ;)

Comment: @r3mus The issue I have with it is that then the attributes are set in two different places; `attr2` within the `new_tag()` call and `class` outside of it. I could put them all outside, I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
>>> attributes = {'class': 'left_padded', 'attr2': '...'}
>>> div = soup.new_tag('div', **attributes)
>>> div
<div attr2="..." class="left_padded"></div>
```

This unpacks the `attributes` dictionary into keyword arguments using the `**` operator, corresponding to `**attrs` in the function signature of `soup.new_tag()`. I don't think this is any more elegant than your solution using `div['class']`, though.

Comment: IMO this is more elegant since it keeps all the attributes together. Will leave the question open a while longer to see if any other solutions arise.